# how to fixed date picker issue

Tags: android

```
  datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DateDialogStyle, this, calendarDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
  calendarDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendarDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
  Calendar then = Calendar.getInstance();
  then.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
  datePicker.setMaxDate(then.getTimeInMillis());
```

[image]

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: Question is not clear plz edit what exactly you want @vikassingh

Comment: @AlexRmcf  my date picker show  two date at time  in android  version 6  but ,i am using greater than  android version 6   then working fine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.